# How to prevent Gnome-shell's Alt+Tab from grouping windows from similar apps?

Tags: gnome-shell, alt-tab

I love pretty much everything about how Gnome Shell handles app-switching through <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. My one gripe with it, though, is how it forces the user to use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ whatever key above the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key for non-US keyboard layouts) to switch between windows of the same app. This is very annoying for me, because now I have to keep in mind if the last window I was using belonged to the same app as the current window or not. Definitely a nuisance for power users who thinks in terms of "windows I'm working with" instead of "applications I'm working on".

I've tried the [AlternateTab extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/), but it's looks way too ugly for me. Not to mention that in the end all I want is to remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>(key above tab)</kbd> to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> on this application. I guess one option would be to just tweak Gnome-shell. My guess is that I should tinker with the `altTab.js` file at `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/`, but the file is too long and overwhelming for someone like me, who doesn't know JavaScript.

Does anyone know how I can make Gnome Shell stop grouping windows by applications?

Comment: 2023 TLDR: Configure your shortcuts under _(Settings App)_ > _Keyboard_ > _View and customize Shortcuts_ > _Navigation_, and here _Switch windows_ or _Switch windows directly_.

Answer (score 247, accepted):

For anyone who is using Ubuntu 18 (to give you the same behavior as e.g. on Windows10):

- go to settings > devices > keyboard
- look for the keyboard shortcut for "Switch windows"
- set this to the shortcut Alt+Tab (this will overwrite the old shortcut)

If you now press Alt+Tab you will be able to directly select all open windows without grouping into the different apps.

Update: In Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS, this is already the default behaviour.

Comment: Right, since 2018, this is the [way recommended by the AlternateTab extension author](https://blogs.gnome.org/fmuellner/2018/10/11/the-future-of-alternatetab-and-why-you-need-not-worry/). [Discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/9nhmce/you_dont_need_alternatetab_extension/)

Comment: Switch windows only works on the current workspace. I still wonder why you cannot just switch windows across workspaces.. this is driving me nuts.

Comment: @Damocles I think that is intended behaviour though. At least for me it makes sense that different workspaces are not just "different screens", but somehow "different computers", i.e. different workspaces. I almost never use workspaces, and you may use them differently, but when I do use them I have one for work and one for personal things. I therefore actually prefer having them separated and have Alt+Tab not show windows from both.

Comment: @Damocles Check the most upvoted answer below for a way to achieve that. You need to uncheck the `/org/gnome/shell/window-switcher/current-workspace-only` setting. This is one way: `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only false`

Comment: Needed to re-enable switch applications (for a less crowded experience), and this still helped.

Comment: In 2023, Gnome 44.1, you'll want to:
* Open Settings
* Click Keyboard in the left Panel (scroll down to it)
* In the right panel under 'Keyboard Shortcuts' click 'View and Customise Shortcuts'
* In the new popup select 'Navigation' 
* Scroll down to find 'Switch Windows' which you can set to 'Alt-tab'.

Comment: The main problem with this solution is it also disables the Multitasking/Application Switching selection, so if you've selected "Include applications from the current workspace only", that will be ignored, and it'll show every application running, which is frustrating.

Comment: @Damocles Looks like that's changed, which is unfortunate, because I never want to switch windows across workspaces. That defeats the purpose of workspaces. Just switch to the workspace first...

Comment: @oligofren On 22.04, that setting no longer has any effect. The default hard-coded behavior is to show all applications across all workspaces with no option to change it.

Comment: @Cerin I am not using Ubuntu or Gnome at the moment, so I cannot confirm, but you are probably right. It's hard to notice something becoming the default once you made it work :-)

Answer (score 412):

- Open `dconf-editor`
- Go to `org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings`
- Move the value `'<Alt>Tab'` from `switch-applications` to `switch-windows`
- Optionally move `'<Shift><Alt>Tab'` from `switch-applications-backward` to `switch-windows-backward`
- If you want `switch-windows` to work across desktops, not just in the current desktop, you can also uncheck `org/gnome/shell/window-switcher/current-workspace-only` (Courtesy of @CharlBotha)
- Close `dconf-editor`
- If using X11, press `<Alt>F2`, then type `r` to restart Gnome.

The last step does not always appear to be necessary, but it should not hurt (especially since it does not close any of your running applications). It will not work, and is not necessary for Wayland.

Comment: Had a special case where pestophagous' answer didn't help, but yours did. In my case, `switch-applications` had both `'<Alt>Tab'` *and* `'<Super>Tab'` assigned to it, while `switch-windows` had just assigned `'<Alt>Tab'` to it. Obviously the setting for `switch-applications` "won" and thus I couldn't switch windows anymore. The Gnome control center dialog did not display the mapping correctly but `dconf-editor` did. I migrated from Ubuntu's gnome-flashback to Gnome 3. Maybe that caused the artifact.

Comment: To have the `switch-windows` work across workspaces, uncheck `org.gnome.shell.window-switcher.current-workspace-only` using `dconf-editor`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.10 I had to `apt install dconf-editor` first, not sure if it's included in other distros.

Comment: Just an addendum, Alt+F2 -> r doesn't work in Wayland.

Comment: For extra laziness https://superuser.com/a/1517491/384307

Comment: `dconf-editor` has not been installed by default in Ubuntu for at least half a decade. You can probably still get it, but you might as well just use the `dconf` or `gsettings` CLI utils as well. This is how to disable the current workspace setting for instance; `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only false`

Answer (score 145):

From the comment by 'xaeth' on this [Ergo Project blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20130117005937/http://planet.ergo-project.org/blog/jmeeuwen/2012/01/31/gnome-3-alt-tab-keyboard-addicts), I have learned that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> will cycle through all windows without grouping by application.  This was the simplest solution for me, and I'm glad it saved me from having to install other programs.

If testing with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> turns out favorably for you, then you can go to  **System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation** and reassign <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to perform the navigation task that was previously assigned to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.  In my settings this task is named 'Switch windows directly'.

Comment: It doesn't give the same behavior. The expected behavior is to quick jump to the needed window. This is kind of a scroll jump, meaning you scroll over each windows, need to visually process each view until you stop at the desired one.

Comment: Does not unstack the windows for me, nor allow me to cycle through windows. It still cycles through applications. Maybe I should login again? Weird.

Comment: **Doesn't work in Ubuntu 16**

Comment: @Waldir Leoncio. Set Alt+Tab to "Switch windows" instead of "Switch windows directly" and the thick frame should disappear. Gnome 3.26

Comment: This solution doesn't show the panel displaying all open windows, most voted solution does.

Comment: Alt+Esc only does open windows. Same on Windows.

Answer (score 57):

Little help -

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and then when you have grouped windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>  helps a bit.

Answer (score 26):

> **AlternateTab**
>
> Substitute Alt-Tab with a window based switcher that does not group by application. This extension is part of Classic Mode and is officially supported by GNOME. Please do not report bugs using the form below, use GNOME Bugzilla instead.

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/

Comment: It seems to be supported already without the need to install the extension.
See post from the developer: https://blogs.gnome.org/fmuellner/2018/10/11/the-future-of-alternatetab-and-why-you-need-not-worry

Comment: works in PoPOS also

Answer (score 18):

The [Windows Alt Tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/38/windows-alt-tab/) extension by [tglman](https://extensions.gnome.org/accounts/profile/tglman) is very useful. You can also [fork it on GitHub](https://github.com/romeshell/windows-alt-tab).

Comment: No need an extension, see this comment https://superuser.com/a/860001/914650. It worked on my Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 15):

Don't know if it works like this for all OSes, but for **Ubuntu 18.04** go to: Settings → Devices → Key

Then look for *Switch windows* which in my case is *disabled* and set it to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

This switches between all windows and displays the horizontal selection box if we hold the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down after tabbing.

---

There are other interesting entries there, namely *Switch applications* and *Switch windows of an application* which I have set for <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> respectively.

Comment: Also works for Fedora 30

Answer (score 14):

You can use the terminal to edit the preferences for the default switcher (This is a command-line equivalent of Mad Physicist's dconf-editor answer.)

run:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-applications "[]"
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-applications-backward "[]"
```

or:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<alt>Tab']"
etc...
```

(As a regular user - not root!!!)

Comment: In bionic, `$ dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-applications-backward "[]"` says `error: 0-2:unable to infer type`

Comment: Thanks!  My alternative to the currently-accepted "cycling-in-place" answer by @pestophagous via the command line is `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"` and `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings cycle-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Tab']"`
That allows me to see the windows in context at full resolution, so I can see if e.g. a browser page has the tab I'm looking for.

Comment: @nealmcb I have changed by running dconf gui application and set to not use default but `[]`

Answer (score 13):

Using fedora 23 you can do the following

Install alternate-tab (was already installed for me)

```
sudo dnf install gnome-shell-extension-alternate-tab
```

Run pref editor

```
gnome-shell-extension-prefs
```

Then enable it

[image]

DONE, alt tab is no longer lame. Also its not some hack like the above with changing the keyboard short cuts. Alt-tab will still show the popup with thumbnails etc, just not grouped.

#### EDIT:

As Ubuntu has now switched back to Gnome I found myself trying to fix this issue again. It's even simpler if you have the gnome web plugin, just visit the `alternate-tab` plugin and click enable and it will be instantly fixed.

[alternate tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/)

[image: alternate tab]

Answer (score 12):

Script for executing on the command line (based on Mad Physicist's awesome answer):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.window-switcher current-workspace-only "false"
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://www.wiredrevolution.com/gnome/fix-alt-tab-task-switching-in-gnome-shell) has shed some light on the subject. By accessing 
**apps -> metacity -> global_keybindings** on gconf-editor there's a key called `switch_group`, which is mapped to `<Alt>Above_Tab`. Changing that to `<Alt>Tab` should solve the issue.

Comment: Hi wleoncio, the above post is telling about a different problem (compared with the question). I tried with your answer, but nothing happened

Comment: @HoàngLong, Metacity was a popular GTK2 window manager. Modern OSs have moved on to GTK3 several years ago, so my 6-year old solution is likely not working for up-to-date systems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the a different application switcher - can enabled using compizconfig-settings-manager.

See good info on CompizConfig in [Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/433039/13330). It can also be installed on [openSUSE](http://software.opensuse.org/package/compizconfig-settings-manager) and probably other distributions.

Result example:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to download anything, nor even use a gui if you do:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "['<Super>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"
```

Obviously, you can leave the keybinding for `switch-applications` blank (`"[]"`) if you never want to use it.

This works on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: You need to handle the backward cases as well:  `switch-applications-backward` and `switch-windows-backward`.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of readjusting the gnome default shortcuts.

```bash
# run as regular user
dconf load / <<EOF
[org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings]
switch-applications=['<Super>Tab']
switch-applications-backward=['<Shift><Super>Tab']
switch-windows=['<Alt>Tab']
switch-windows-backward=['<Shift><Alt>Tab']
EOF
```

This will use `Alt-Tab` to change to the *next window* while still keeping `Super-Tab` iterate through *applications*.

Answer (score 1):

The following works on **CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009**

Settings --> Devices --> Keyboard --> Navigation --> Switch windows

[image: Screenshot for clarity]

Answer (score 1):

```shell
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows "['<Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-windows-backward "['<Shift><Alt>Tab']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications "[]"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-applications-backward "[]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I was able to do it was install the dconf editor from the Ubuntu Software Store. From there, you can follow the path -> /org.gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings.
[Path View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0zHp.png)

If you scroll down, you will see switch-applications which I change to ['Tab'] and right below it is switch-application-backwards which is now ['Tab'].

[Switch Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4AgV.png)

Scrolling down, you will see switch-windows and switch-windows-backwards. You can set this to ['Tab'] and ['Tab'] respectively.

[Switch Windows Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmayF.png)

Just figured Id share. New to Ubuntu and this took me about an hour of googling to figure out. This definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome Shell on Gnome 3.34.3 in Ubuntu 19.10 x86_64, Settings, Devices, Keyboard Shortcuts, Navigation, Switch windows "Alt+Tab" doesn't group, but also doesn't include minimized windows like the [Coverflow Alt-Tab extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/) does, which also overrides the normal grouped Switch applications "Super+Tab" for no reason.