# GNOME: switch-windows only on active workspace

Tags: linux, gnome

I changed alt+tab to switch-windows as shown in this answer: [How to prevent Gnome-shell's Alt+Tab from grouping windows from similar apps?](https://superuser.com/questions/394376/how-to-prevent-gnome-shells-alttab-from-grouping-windows-from-similar-apps/860001#860001)

Now I have the problem that if I press alt+tab it shows me all open windows and not only windows of the current workspace. I thought "current-workspace-only" in "/org/gnome/shell/window-switcher" would prevent this behaviour, but it doesn't.

How can I prevent "switch-windows" from switching to other workspaces?

Comment: Excuse me dun, but why haven't you accepted my answer? It is a perfectly valid answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start gnome-tweak-tool, go to Extensions, turn Alternatetab "ON".

[gnome-tweak-tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50pFY.png)
[image]